# MySQL fetch multiple values with one query and turn them into printable variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

i have a question regarding the simplification of my PHP code.

I am building a product selection module for a webshop. I want to fetch the value of certain columns from the top 3 rows from a table called 'BestProducts'.

Let's say I would like to know the Product price of the first, second and third product in the table.
With the PHP skills I have at the moment, I would query the database 3 times, to fetch the product price of the three products individually. After the query I would convert the results from object into a printable variable (also individually).

I'm sure there must be a more efficient and thus less time/performance consuming way to fetch these three prices and to turn them into printable variables, so that I can show the prices on my webpage.

I think i should fetch three product prices by using only one query, and then extract this query into three separate variables. I do not know, however, how to do this exactly. Help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Sounds like you need a JOIN between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIMIT to limit the amount of results that yor query will output, try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable LIMIT 0,3  ORDER BY somecolumn
```

this result will output the first 3 results of the table ordered by the specified column, and then fetch them in a loop, maybe using this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to get the first 3 rows of your BestProducts table, to do that you can make a query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT your_column1, your_column2, your_columnN FROM BestProduct ORDER BY your_criteria DESC LIMIT 3;
```

I will suppose you already have a connection with your database, so the next step it's to execute the query and iterate over the result

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

     /* to get the associative array */
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["your_column1"], $row["your_column2"]);
     }
     /* free the result set*/
     $result->free();
}
```

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: If you don't have a connection with your database, simply add `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");` before the if

Comment: thanks a lot! Now how can I print a certain value from the array? Let's say I would like to have the second value from the column 'ProductPrice'. How can I select it from the array and assign it to a variable?

Comment: What fetch_assoc() return is an array of the row you are currently at. So to get the value from ProductPrice you need to do this inside the while `$productPrice = $row['ProductPrice'];` Now to get the second value you can either change your query to get the specific value you want or add a counter something like `$counter = 0; while( .....) { //code if ($counter++ == 1){ //do something } `